# unable to get marquee effect

Tags: java, swing, marquee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Marquee effect in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617326/marquee-effect-in-java-swing)

I am trying to obtain marquee effect (the same we have in html). But I am unable to do so with this code. How can I improve this code to obtain marquee effect?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class tester {
JLabel l;

tester() {
JFrame fr=new JFrame();
JPanel p=new JPanel();
l=new JLabel("");
fr.add(p);
p.add(l);
fr.setVisible(true);
fr.setSize(400,400);
fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void MarqueeEffect() {
  ActionListener ac = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      l.setText("To action alone hast thou a right and never at all to its fruits let not the   fruits of action be thy motive; neither let there be in thee any attachment to inaction");
    }
  };
  new Timer(2000,ac).start();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  tester t=new tester();
  t.MarqueeEffect();
 }
}
```

Comment: This is homework, isn't it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to extend `JLabel` and override `paintComponent` to bring marquee effect. It wont come just by setting text to it without extending JLabel. You can do something like this in your customized JLabel class.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{         
g.translate((int)((System.currentTimeMillis() / MARQUEE_SPEED_DIV) % (getWidth() * 2)) - getWidth(), 0);         
super.paintComponent(g);        
repaint(REPAINT_WITHIN_MS);     
}
```