# Java animation stutters when not moving mouse cursor

Tags: java, swing, animation

I have a quite simple animation, a text in a big font moving continuously (pixel by pixel) to the left. The text is first converted to an image, then a timer task is started which repeatedly (every 10-20 ms) decrements the x coordinate of the image by 1, and does a repaint().

This program shows a strange behavior on some systems. On my PC with a nVidia card it runs smoothly. On my Vaio notebook, on a BeagleBoneBlack and on a friend's Mac it stutters heavily. It appears to pause for a while, then jump to the left about 10 pixels, pause again and so on.

What stumps me is the fact that on these systems the animation *only* stutters if you don't touch the mouse. As long as you move the mouse cursor within the window, no matter how slowly, or drag the window itself around, the animation runs perfectly smooth!

Can anybody explain this? Here is the program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Textimg extends JComponent
{
    String      str;
    Font        font;
    int         x = 0;
    final int   ytext = 136;
    Image       img;

    public Textimg(String s)
    {
        str = s;
        font = new Font("Noserif", Font.PLAIN, 96);
        setLayout(null);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if (img == null)
        {
            img = createImage(4800, 272);
            Graphics gr = img.getGraphics();

            gr.setFont(font);
            gr.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            gr.fillRect(0, 0, 4800, 272);
            gr.setColor(new Color(135, 175, 0));
            gr.drawString(str, 0, ytext);
            gr.dispose();
        }

        g.drawImage(img, x, 0, this);
    }

    public void addX(int dif)
    {
        if (isVisible())
        {
            x = x + dif;

            Graphics g = getGraphics();

            if (g != null) paintComponent(g);
        }
    }
} 


public class Banner extends JFrame 
{ 
    StringBuffer    buf;
    int             sleeptime = 10;

    Banner(String path) throws IOException 
    { 
        setSize(new Dimension(480, 272));
        setTitle("Java Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "UTF-8"));

        buf = new StringBuffer();

        while (true) 
        {
           String line = reader.readLine();

           if (line == null) break;
           buf.append(line);
        }

        final Textimg textimg = new Textimg(buf.toString());

        add(textimg);
        textimg.setBounds(0, 0, 480, 272);

        final javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(200, new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                textimg.addX(-1);
            }
        });

        timer.setDelay(sleeptime);
        timer.start();
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new Banner(args[0]).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 44):

Try calling this method when you are done drawing:

```
 Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
```

This flushs the graphics buffer which some systems like Linux use. See the Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#sync()

Comment: This fixed the stutter for me as is (on a Chrubuntu 14.04 Acer C720), but I switched it to `frame.getToolkit().sync();` to avoid globals.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much, I've been trying to fix this bug for hours! Also used `getToolkit().sync()` in the frame after the call to `repaint()`. (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: This answer helped me today.

Comment: How would you 'implement' this for the animation of for example an *indeterminate* `JProgressBar` animation of the Nimbus LAF? This problem sounds more like a bona fide bug.

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: @Martin What's the advantage of `frame.getToolkit().sync();` over `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();`?

Comment: @PaulWalker - I have no recollection of what this was about, but sounds like it was just to avoid using a static method when a non-static was available.

Answer (score 3):

- Don't, EVER, use `getGraphics` and you should NEVER call `paintComponent` yourself, this not how custom painting is done in Swing. Instead, update the state and call `repaint`.
- Don't rely on magic numbers, use the information you have at hand (`getWidth` and `getHeight`)
- Swing components are doubled buffered, so it's unlikely you would need to create you own buffered strategy. This simple act could be slowing down your painting
- You must call `super.paintComponent`. This is even more important with `JComponent`, as it is not opaque and failing to do so could result in some nasty paint artefacts.
- You should override `JComponent#getPreferredSize` so it can work with layout managers for efficiently.
- You may find a shorter delay produces a better illusion, say 40 milliseconds (roughly 25fps) for example

Take a look at [Swing animation running extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886232/swing-animation-running-extremely-slow/14902184#14902184), which through some object management and optimisation, was able to increase from 500 animated objects up to 4500.

Also take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) in particular

Answer (score 2):

[Profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) shows that you are saturating the shared thread used by `javax.swing.Timer`. One mitigation strategy is to use a longer period and/or a larger increment/decrement, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3621417/230513).

Addendum: In addition, you are laboriously re-rendering the entire image in each call to `paintComponent()`. Instead, render it *once* using `TextLayout`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282330/230513), and `draw()` only the newly visible portion each time.

[image]

Comment: See also `MarqueePanel`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6817829/230513).

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into TextLayout, never used that before. However, IMHO the fact that the animation runs smoothly whenever I move the mouse clearly shows that a resource bottleneck can't be the reason.

Comment: Results will vary by platform; on my system, the the mouse has no effect. I'd hoist the relatively expensive rendering out of the implicit timer loop. Your basic approach is sound and potentially smoother than character based schemes.

Comment: I experminented a little more. The effect is completely independent of the text length, and even present if in the loop I do nothing but `x = x -1; setLocation(x, 0);`.

Comment: And I tried other Java versions: Java 6 is similar, Java 8 EA is worse, but in Java 5 it works just fine on my notebook, the animation runs smoothly, no need to move the mouse. So I guess it is a bug that crept into Java 6. Now I have a different problem -  Oracle doesn't offer a Java 5 JRE for ARM processors.

Comment: If you're still using `getGraphics()`, I'm not surprised. I've panned large bitmaps on 5, 6 & 7; haven't tried 8. Please edit your question to update your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) to the current code.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem solved!

To answer my own question: After realizing that *any* continuous input (mouse or keyboard) makes the animation run smoothly, I remembered that inputs can be generated by the program itself, using an object of the class `java.awt.Robot`. That lead to a simple workaround:
Create a Robot and let it press a key or a mouse move in each animation cycle.

```
final Robot robot = new Robot();
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(initialDelay, new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // update your image...

        robot.keyPress(62);
     }
});
```

This is a kludge, but works perfectly.

Comment: How did you choose the number 62?

Comment: Haha, what an approach