# Update JPanel and attributes in a gui, with a user-specified timer?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

So I have this class. We'll call it ProcessBox. I have another class called Process that has a ProcessBox as a member variable. Then, in my main method I have an ArrayList of Process objects (each having their own ProcessBox). How would I go about making it so that my ProcessBox would update every x ms (where x is user specified. I already have the listener for inputting x done). Below is my ProcessBox class. This is what I wish to redraw every x ms (except a whole list of them).

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import java.util.*;

public class ProcessBox extends JPanel {
    GridBagLayout gbc_panel;

    public ProcessBox(Process p) {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbc_panel.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
        gbc_panel.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        gbc_panel.columnWeights = new double[] { 0, 0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        gbc_panel.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                Double.MIN_VALUE };
        super.setLayout(gbc_panel);


        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 110));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(110, 110));
        setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1));
        setSize(new Dimension(110, 110));

        String name = p.getName();
        int priority = p.getPriority();
        int minPriority = p.getMinPriority();
        ArrayList<Integer> times = p.getTime();
        Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        setBackground(new Color(r.nextInt(255 - 210) + 210,
                r.nextInt(255 - 210) + 210, r.nextInt(255 - 210) + 210));

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("ID:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 0;
        add(lblNewLabel, gbc_lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(name);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblNewLabel_1.gridy = 0;
        add(lblNewLabel_1, gbc_lblNewLabel_1);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Priority:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblNewLabel_2.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel_2.gridy = 2;
        add(lblNewLabel_2, gbc_lblNewLabel_2);

        JLabel lblNum = new JLabel(Integer.toString(priority));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNum = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNum.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblNum.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblNum.gridy = 2;
        add(lblNum, gbc_lblNum);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("Min:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel_3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel_3.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblNewLabel_3.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel_3.gridy = 3;
        add(lblNewLabel_3, gbc_lblNewLabel_3);

        JLabel lblMp = new JLabel(Integer.toString(minPriority));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblMp = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblMp.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblMp.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblMp.gridy = 3;
        add(lblMp, gbc_lblMp);

        JLabel lblTimeSlice = new JLabel("Slice:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblTimeSlice = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblTimeSlice.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_lblTimeSlice.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblTimeSlice.gridy = 4;
        add(lblTimeSlice, gbc_lblTimeSlice);

        JLabel lblLeft = new JLabel(Integer.toString(times.get(0)));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblLeft = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblLeft.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblLeft.gridy = 4;
        add(lblLeft, gbc_lblLeft);
        setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Comment: What do I do within this swing timer? I'm new to GUI.

Comment: Did you read the API? Did you follow the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Timers"? Did you download and try the example? What part of the example didn't you understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and look at [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user:230513%20javax.swing.timer), e.g. [`MarqueeTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3621417/230513) or [`AnimationTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3256941/230513).

Comment: I'll try this out and report back later. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent. Don't hesitate to refine your question with an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) based on your findings.

Comment: I'm not really certain how I'll apply this to my code but I know it is the right way.