# Changing Color of a Java graphic object

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, repaint

I'm trying to flash a Java graphic object by changing the color and calling the `repaint()` method. The color is only updating with the final change color call. Here is my code:

```
public void start() {
    try {
        Color origColor = node.getColor();
        for (int i=0; i<noOfFlashes; i++) {
            Manager.gui.getDrawGraph().changeNodeColor(node, Color.WHITE);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            Manager.gui.getDrawGraph().changeNodeColor(node, origColor);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        Manager.gui.getDrawGraph().changeNodeColor(node, Graph.VISITED_NODE);       
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the change node color method is:

```
public void changeNodeColor(Node node, Color c) {
    node.setColor(c);
    repaint();
}
```

The change node color is in the same class as the paint component.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you a using a thread to achieve this ?

Comment: No. Its single threaded. the thread command i used to pause the execution.

Comment: How is the `start()` method called? Does the GUI-thread call it (via button or other events) or do you actually call it from a different thread?

Comment: Yes the gui thread calls it via button.

Comment: @Josh Then you have to make a new thread and do it in parallel or else you are blocking the handling of the repaint events until you are finished with your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use separate thread to manage your GUI event. 
You can do this, using a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), as suggested by Amine, or implement the [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, or extend the [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class, developing the `run()` method, that is the task of your thread.

You can read this old question of SO : [How do I use SwingWorker in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java)

A tutorial for SwingWorker : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

A tutorial to make a Thread : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

> The color is only updating with the final change color call.

If you don't use a separate thread, your gui will freezing until the method is completely executed, and you won't see the color change separated by `Thread.sleep(500);`.

**UPDATE**

In [this](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~simhaweb/java/faq/faq.html) link, in the paragraph *Why does a Swing GUI freeze or lock up?*, you can understand why a Java Swing GUI freezes, with the use of a single thread.

Check also [this](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html) official link, in the paragraph *Creating Threads*, and [this](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads3.html) page, that returns:

> Swing's single-thread rule says that Swing components can only be
>   accessed by a single thread. This rule applies to both gets and sets,
>   and the single thread is known as the event-dispatch thread.
>
> The single-thread rule is a good match for UI components because they
>   tend to be used in a single-threaded way anyway, with most actions
>   being initiated by the user. Furthermore, building thread safe
>   components is difficult and tedious: it's a good thing not to be doing
>   if it can be avoided. But for all its benefits, the single-thread rule
>   has far-reaching implications.
>
> Swing components will generally not comply with the single-thread rule
>   unless all their events are sent and received on the event-dispatch
>   thread. For example, property-change events should be sent on the
>   event-dispatch thread, and model-change events should be received on
>   the event-dispatch thread.
>
> For model-based components such as JTable and JTree, the single-thread
>   rule implies that the model itself can only be accessed by the
>   event-dispatch thread. For this reason, the model's methods must
>   execute quickly and should never block, or the entire user interface
>   will be unresponsive.

I think that the sentences above are very useful to understand better the `Swing` package.

I report the suggestion of trashgod.

You can use the `Timer` class, from the `javax.swing.Timer` package. That is also a good alternative.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237085/update-jpanel-and-attributes-in-a-gui-with-a-user-specified-timer/8237370#8237370) question, trashgod reports some examples of `Timer`.

Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a tutorial about `Timer`.

Comment: +1 [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8237370/230513), is another alternative.

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for the vote, the suggestion, and the link to your question. Your questions, are always very useful and nice. ;-) The Timer is also a good alternative. I edit my answer to insert the link to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what i understand from your code, I will probably recommend the use of [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

I know you do not have any cost expensive code but you using SwingWorker, you will be able to update your GUI more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which framework you're using here... but you may need a repaint() just before the Thread.sleep().  Is there a Manager.gui.repaint() perhaps? (Sorry, complete guesswork here...)

Comment: I think he is using Java Swing here.