# Delayed "Typing Effect" Title

Tags: java, swing

How would you make a String title be animated to type in a JFrame? I am trying to get a title that says "Welcome to Application....", but places each letter one at a time with a delay in between them all. I would like this to be a method that I can call at other times if I wanted to.

Right now I am thinking it is Timer, but not really sure how to go about this.

Any help would be appreciated.

It appear like this https://thelocalyarn.com/images/cursor1.gif

Comment: Please clearly state what is required.

Comment: Yes, (swing) timer sounds good. You repeatedly update the title and add a letter at a time.

Comment: Yes, try it with a Swing `Timer` and get back to us when you have an attempt (a [mcve]) and a *specific* question. Voting to close as 'too broad'.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3621417/230513).